# creating an autorelease pool and draining it in a different context

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, autorelease

In a view controller I have a UIImageView as a subview. On willRotateToInterfaceOrientation, i replace it with a different UIImageView. If both are in memory at the same time, it sometimes jettison crashes because the images are very big. So i want to make sure I completely dealloc the first one before making the new one. When i call removeFromSuperview on it, I think it is basically autoreleasing at some point later, but I need it to be dealloced immediately.

So it seems i need my own autorelease pool when the UIImageView is created, and then drain it when willRotateToInterfaceOrientation gets called, after the removeFromSuperview call. But the documentation says:

> An autorelease pool should always be drained in the same context (such
>   as the invocation of a method or function, or the body of a loop) in
>   which it was created. Autorelease pools are used “inline.” There
>   should typically be no reason why you should make an autorelease pool
>   an instance variable of an object.

So what is the "right" way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is optimize your images. It is imperative that an autorelease pool is allocated and drained within the same context. First thing you should is try to reduce the size of the image. If they are png's try `pngcrush`. If the images are still to large consider using `mmap` to load portions of the image at a time.

[Performance Tuning](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html)

> **Impose size limits on resources.**
>  Avoid loading a large resource file when a smaller one will do. Instead of using a high-resolution
>   image, use one that is appropriately sized for iOS-based devices. If
>   you must use large resource files, find ways to load only the portion
>   of the file that you need at any given time. For example, rather than
>   load the entire file into memory, use the mmap and munmap functions to
>   map portions of the file into and out of memory. For more information
>   about mapping files into memory, see File-System Performance
>   Guidelines.

Comment: will reducing the disk size of the image with compression make a difference to the RAM footprint after it's loaded in as a UIImage? I assumed that it would always be stored uncompressed in RAM?

Comment: It will at a minimum help reduce the memory peak since it has load the image from disk to get it in RAM.

Comment: ah ok, thanks. but the actual filesize pales in comparison to the uncompressed images.. and i could reduce the peak by half if i could dealloc the old image before making the new one, is there really no way to do this? mmap looks interesting by the way, i didn't know about that..

Comment: I suppose you could try delaying loading the next image until the next run loop which should give the autorelease pool time to clean up. Try using `(void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay` and passing 0 for the delay.

Comment: your last suggestion is what i've ended up doing, thanks for that. it seems to be the only thing that actually makes sure the old stuff is removed from memory before the new one is made. it means there's a short period of black screen inbetween, but i think that's unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

Think of autorelease pools as thread local stacks. You do not persist across contexts or other autorelease pools -- messing up the ordering. Having an autorelease pool as an ivar is often a mistake. Using an autorelease pool from multiple threads is also a mistake.

Create one every place you need it, and destroy in that context, on that thread, without messing up the ordering, and you'll be fine. That may imply creating and destroying one in each method you mentioned. They are quite fast to create and destroy.

If you need to hold a reference to another object (e.g. your image) beyond that context to ensure it lives as long as you need it, do so.